# Importing JSON data to SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Sample data looks like this:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ff1e194b6a9d73a3a9f1052"
  },
  "active": true,
  "createdDate": {
    "$date": 1609687444800
  },
  "lastLogin": {
    "$date": 1609687537858
  },
  "role": "consumer",
  "signUpSource": "Email",
  "state": "WI"
}
```

Here's the extended sample

```json
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ff1e194b6a9d73a3a9f1052"},"active":true,"createdDate":{"$date":1609687444800},"lastLogin":{"$date":1609687537858},"role":"consumer","signUpSource":"Email","state":"WI"}

{"_id":{"$oid":"5ff1e194b6a9d73a3a9f1052"},"active":true,"createdDate":{"$date":1609687444800},"lastLogin":{"$date":1609687537858},"role":"consumer","signUpSource":"Email","state":"WI"}

{"_id":{"$oid":"5ff1e194b6a9d73a3a9f1052"},"active":true,"createdDate":{"$date":1609687444800},"lastLogin":{"$date":1609687537858},"role":"consumer","signUpSource":"Email","state":"WI"}

{"_id":{"$oid":"5ff1e1eacfcf6c399c274ae6"},"active":true,"createdDate":{"$date":1609687530554},"lastLogin":{"$date":1609687530597},"role":"consumer","signUpSource":"Email","state":"WI"}
```

What I have tried -

```sql
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK 'C:\Users\shahk\OneDrive\Desktop\FetchAssgn\users.json', 
    FORMATFILE= 'C:\Users\shahk\OneDrive\Desktop\FetchAssgn\csv.fmt') AS [Json]
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (json)
    WITH  (
oid varchar(50)  ,
state varchar(5)     ,
Date datetime   ,
date datetime   ,
role varchar(10)    ,
signUpSource varchar(10),
active varchar(10)   
              
        ) AS users
```

Output I get:

[image]

What I require is the output without Null in id, createdDate and lastLogin columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this...

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ff1e194b6a9d73a3a9f1052"
  },
  "active": true,
  "createdDate": {
    "$date": 1609687444800
  },
  "lastLogin": {
    "$date": 1609687537858
  },
  "role": "consumer",
  "signUpSource": "Email",
  "state": "WI"
}';

select oid, state, createdDate, lastLogin, role, signUpSource, active
from openjson(@json) WITH  (
  oid varchar(50) '$._id."$oid"',
  state varchar(5),
  cd bigint '$.createdDate."$date"',
  ll bigint '$.lastLogin."$date"',
  role varchar(10)    ,
  signUpSource varchar(10),
  active varchar(10)   
) AS users
cross apply (
  select
    createdDate = dateadd(ss, cd/1000, '1970-01-01'),
    lastLogin = dateadd(ss, ll/1000, '1970-01-01')
) calc;
```

Which yields...

| oid | state | createdDate | lastLogin | role | signUpSource | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5ff1e194b6a9d73a3a9f1052 | WI | 2021-01-03 15:24:04.000 | 2021-01-03 15:25:37.000 | consumer | Email | true |

There are a couple of tricks to be aware of here:

1. In SQL Server JSON path expressions don't support bare `$` characters in property names. Properties that include `$` characters need to be quoted, so `$oid` needs to be `"$oid"`, `$date` needs to be `"$date"`, etc..
2. On SQL Server the Unix epoch `$date` values will overflow `int` storage so need to be deserialized as `bigint` types.
3. The [`dateadd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) function's numeric parameter is of type `int`, so to avoid `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int` errors you'll need to divide the millisecond values by 1,000 and use them as seconds instead.